# Managing UART buffer Thingy91

Tags: c, buffer, uart

I have a Thingy91 Nordic device, and I am integrating it with a sensor that works at 1200 baud rate. It basically sends strings that i need to store in a buffer and parse for usage. However I am facing a peculiar issue wherein I am getting the correct string the 1st time I recieve data, but after that I recieve garbage values.

Below is the part of the code:

```
uint8_t message_buf[100];
void uart_cb(struct device *x) {
  uart_irq_update(x);

  if (uart_irq_rx_ready(x)) {
    uart_fifo_read(x, message_buf, sizeof(message_buf));
    printk("%s", message_buf);
  }
}

void main(){

struct device *uart = device_get_binding(UART_PORT);
......
uart_irq_callback_set(uart, uart_cb);
......
}
```

We think that it might be a problem in managing the message_buf while getting the new string, and wanted to know the correct procedure of managing the buffer. Also,what could be the root cause that I get correct data on the first call and get garbage values later on.

Regards,
Adeel.

Comment: Have you checked the return value from uart_fifo_read? According to the documentation, it should be called until the entire fifo has been emptied. If it holds more data than fits in message_buf and you only call the function once, there will be undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [API document](https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/0.4.0/zephyr/reference/peripherals/uart.html#_CPPv314uart_fifo_readP6deviceP4u8_tKi):

```
static int uart_fifo_read(structdevice *dev, u8_t *rx_data, const int size)
```

> Read data from FIFO.
> This function is expected to be called from UART interrupt handler (ISR), if uart_irq_rx_ready() returns true. Result of calling this function not from an ISR is undefined (hardware-dependent). It’s unspecified whether “RX ready” condition as returned by uart_irq_rx_ready() is level- or edge- triggered. *That means that once uart_irq_rx_ready() is detected, uart_fifo_read() must be called until it reads all available data in the FIFO (i.e. until it returns less data than was requested).*

**Returns:** Number of bytes read.

**Parameters:**
`dev`: UART device structure.
`rx_data`: Data container.
`size`: Container size.

It clearly specifies that the API must be called until the return value is lesser than requested number of bytes (`size`).

Your code:

```
if (uart_irq_rx_ready(x)) {
    uart_fifo_read(x, message_buf, sizeof(message_buf));
    printk("%s", message_buf);
}
```

It calls `uart_fifo_read()` once and then exits the callback `uart_cb`, which deviates from what is recommended.

You should read from FIFO until it is empty:

```
int readBytes = 0;
if (uart_irq_rx_ready(x)) 
{
    do{ 
        readBytes += uart_fifo_read(x, &message_buf[readBytes], (sizeof(message_buf)-readBytes));
    while(readBytes < sizeof(message_buf));

    printk("Received %d bytes: ", readBytes);
    // printk("%s", message_buf); // Certainly the code will crash if it isn't a string that fits in message_buf!
}
```